# Shouldn't "by the thousands" be "in the thousands"?

Tags: prepositions, phrase-usage

I have this question about "*in the thousands*" and "*by the thousands*" [here](http://online.wsj.com/articles/hong-kong-government-students-battle-for-public-opinion-1412947699):

> On Friday night, crowds swelled ***by the thousands*** in downtown Hong Kong to listen to speeches from organizers, signaling the pro-democracy movement still has momentum after calls for a big rally.

Shouldn't "***by*** *the thousands*" be "***in*** *the thousands*"?  Like, "*people came* ***in*** *the thousands*"?

If both "***by*** *the thousands*" and "***in*** *the thousands*" are valid English, how are they different?

Comment: Why do you think "in the thousands" might be OK?

Comment: @user3169 Is "in the thousands" a corruption of "by the thousands"?  I noticed that the article is written by three authors, two of which are likely non-native English speakers.

Comment: Sorry I don't follow you. I did not find "in the thousands" in the article.

Comment: @user3169 What I meant is that "by the thousands" is used in the article when "in the thousands" should be used.

Comment: @user3169 So, The "by" in "*people came* ***by*** *the thousands*" and the "by" in "*Crowds swelled* ***by*** *the thousands*" are different?

Comment: In the case of swelled, its an increase as mentioned. In the case of "people came by the thousands", you could think of it as one thousand, one thousand more (2,000), one thousand more (3,000), etc. Really its still increasing quantity. Saying "People came **in** the thousands" only means that the number that came was something close to a number ending in "thousands".

Answer (score 4):

In English one of the uses of "by" is to describe the quantities of batches.  It has two general forms.

First, in the most literal way, we would say that you can *buy eggs by the dozen* (dozen == 12); eggs come in cartons of 12 eggs each, you cannot buy arbitrary numbers of eggs, you can only buy them in cartons, each of which has twelve.  So at any given time, you can buy 12, 24, 36, etc.  We express this idea by saying that they are sold *by the dozen*.

Second, that locution has come to be used to indicate **scale**.  It is as if it implies, "these are the units you would find most convenient to count them in."  If someone says of a terrible famine, "people died by the score" (score == 20), they do not mean that people literally died in groups of twenty, but that approximately several or many twenties of people  died.  As a native speaker, I would understand that to mean approximately 80 +/- 40.  Or, for another example, "he smoked cigarettes by the pack" does not mean the smoker in question stuck twenty cigarettes in his mouth at once, but that he went through at least one, and possibly several, packs each day, or at least at a fast enough clip to recommend buying them more than one at a time.  If someone says "within weeks, they were selling the new flavor of jam by the ton", it doesn't usually mean the jam was sold in one ton increments, but that the total amount of orders would most naturally be indicated in tons.

With that explained, the passage you're asking about:

> On Friday night, crowds swelled by the thousands in downtown Hong Kong to listen to speeches from organizers

is using the latter sense.  It was not the case that batches of one thousand people were showing up together, but rather some unspecified quantity of people showed up, which was some amount best represented by an approximation of a smallish integer and three zeros.

Comment: In "*people died by the* ***score***", it is singular.  But in "*crowds swelled by the* ***thousands***", it is plural.

Comment: Yes.  Did you have a question about that?

Comment: Could I write "*crowds swelled by the* ***thousand***" instead of "*crowds swelled by the* ***thousands***"?

Comment: Hmm!  That sounds wrong to me; when you use a number, you use the plural, as in the above example "by twos and threes".  But "dozen" is funny; note that it works like "by the pack" and "by the ton" which have to be singular.  While "dozen" does mean "twelve", it perhaps is best thought of as "batch of twelve".

Comment: Does "***the thousands***" refer to a single unspecified number (with three trialing zeros), or a bunch of unspecified numbers (with three trialing zeros)?

Comment: I think, if I understand your question, the former.

Comment: According to this [dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/british/thousand), "the thousands" means ALL the numbers between 1,000 and 10,000.  Could the dictionary be wrong?

Comment: @meatie, read again the entry at the link you just cited.  It does not say "all".  Edited to add: and as the SE interface reminds me: you should not be asking new questions in the comments.  Take questions to a new post.

Answer (score 3):

"People came **in** the thousands" means that thousands of people came.  "People came **by** the thousands" means the same thing, and is equally valid English.

"Crowds swelled **by** the thousands" means that the size of the crowd **increased by** thousands of people.  The word **by** is used to compare the size of the crowd before-versus-after the crowd "swelled".

"Crowds swelled **in** the thousands" is not correct English.

Comment: So, "*people came* ***by*** *the thousands*" would be poor English?

Comment: I would only use "by the thousands" in these examples.

Comment: @meatie, "People came by twos and threes" means people arrived in groups of 2 or 3 at a time. "People came by the thousands" has the same meaning: people came in groups of thousands at a time.

Comment: @ThePhoton So, The "by" in "*people came* ***by*** *the thousands*" and the "by" in "*Crowds swelled* ***by*** *the thousands*" are different?

Comment: @meatie, I think the "crowds swelled" example is poorly written. They might mean it in the same way, "in groups of thousands at a time" or the author might have had some other meaning in mind.

Answer (score 2):

*Crowds swelled by the thousands* suggests that if you were counting the people **coming in**, you'd have to count them in groups of a thousand or more at a time to have an easy-to-count number of groups. This is a rather inexact measurement.

*Crowds swelled **in** the thousands* does not sound right, I'd guess it's non-standard English. [Sometimes](https://www.google.com/webhp#q=%22grew+in+the+thousands%22) *grew in the thousands* is used, but means *grew **to** the thousands*, which is the same meaning as:

*Crowds **numbered in [or grew to]** the thousands* means that the total number of people in the crowd would be measured in the thousands. It does not suggest whether the crowd grew quickly or slowly.

To be more concise: *by [unit]s* suggests **growth**, *in [unit]s* suggests an **end count**.