# By The Dozen/Hundred

Tags: grammar, meaning, usage

Suppose that Ebola is the current issue:

> 1. New cases occurred by the ***dozen***.
> 2. New cases occurred by the ***hundred***.

It seems that second sentence is wrong, because "*hundred*" should be followed by "*s*".  Yet, in the first sentence, "*dozen*" doesn't need the "*s*".  Why is that?

Comment: What is the source, or are there references for your suppositions?

Comment: @user3169 The current question came from this [thread](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/36577/by-the-thousands/36590?noredirect=1#comment67947_36590).  I tried to squeeze the current into that thread, but was told to start a new thread.

Answer (score 1):

You can use *by the dozen* or *by the dozens* depending on context.

[***by the dozen***](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/by+the+dozen) refers to specific quantities of 12, or as a general term for a large quantity.

> Eggs are normally sold **by the dozen**.
>   The government is producing new policies **by the dozen**.

[***by the dozens***](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/by+the+dozens) is more of a generalized term for a large quantity less than "hundreds".

> Just then people began showing up **by the dozens**.

Comment: So, the singular "*the hundred"* could be used like in "*eggs are sold by* ***the hundred***" to refer to eggs being sold in multiples of one hundred?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.